# Allow slash & æ,ø,å in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

As the title says, I simply need to allow a normal slash in preg_match. I thought it was something like / or something. But that doesn't work.

I also need to allow european letters: æ,ø,å. How is this done?

Could someone tell me this? :-)

**Example**

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["last_name"]) == 0)
                {
                    $errMsg = "Dit efternavn må kun indeholde bogstaver, mellemrum og bindestreg.<br>";
                }
```

And then I'm doing a 
`if(count($errMsg)==0){
 }`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be so kind and add an example input and your current code for processing it.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question. Sorry jmz.

Comment: @jmz - do you need more for me to tell?

Comment: [Matching Unicode letters with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131876/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those characters can be used normally, in order to use slashes (`/`). you will need to escape them with a backslash (`\`). Like so:

```
preg_match("%^[-a-zA-Z æøå\/]+$%");
```

Also note that you can use any character as a delimiter, it may be wise to use characters that are not likely to appear in the pattern itself (in this case, I chose `%`).

Comment: More readable but not equialent. AFAIK \s is not only space but all 0x00-0x20 chars (ie tab,newline)

Comment: Besides, you not need escape slash if you use % as delimiter

Comment: btw it could be wise to escape the hyphen as it has a special meaning inside square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Put æøå in your regex to match those characters. To match a slash simply escape it with a single backslash.

Comment: Four slashes? \\? He meant /.

Comment: So it should be like this: [a-zA-Zæøå -\\/]?

Comment: That looks right. And sorry for making the huge mistake of escaping backslashes instead of slashes, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -\/æøå]+$/u", $_POST["last_name"]) == 0)
if(preg_match("~^[a-zA-Z -/æøå]+$~u", $_POST["last_name"]) == 0)
```

`u` modifier is for UTF-8
[Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

You need to escape slash or change delimiter to any other i.e `~` as in second example

**u modofier is important**

Example:

```
$str=ord(166);
if(preg_match('~[æ]~',$str)){
    print 'without';
}
if(preg_match('~[æ]~u',$str)){
    print 'with';
}
```

prints only `without`
In first example `æ` treated as two symbols and every of them is matched