# Regex to match English, special characters and emojis

Tags: regex, dart, regex-group

I'm trying to build a regex to match English with special characters and also the emojis, I found this one `[\u0000-\u007F]+$` for English with special characters and this one `([^\x00-\x7F]+\ *(?:[^\x00-\x7F]| )*)` for emojis but I can't figure how to combine both, any idea how?.

Comment: Do you use  JavaScript?

Comment: No I want this regex to use it in dart code.

Comment: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode - so it depends on encoding right? https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F601

Comment: The 2 parts are almost each other’s opposites (except for the space). What you say is “emojis” is actually anything *not* ascii 0-127.

Comment: that's correct, I just want to combine them to be able to exclude other languages characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to match any string that cannot contain any non-English letter use

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]|\P{L})+$
```

Code sample:

```
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^(?:[a-zA-Z]|\P{L})+$', unicode: true);
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/5xyLt1/1)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \P{L}                   any char other than a Unicode letter
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Nice, it's working, thank you so much, but I've a naive question if you let me, why it's not working on this site https://regexr.com/, is it buggy? because I've been using it all day. I noticed on regexr.com you need to explicitly allow space and new line, is this normal?

Comment: I think regex101 is the buggy one not regexr

Comment: @TheForgottenWarrior I could not make it work at regexr either. This must be a bug, yes.

Comment: No I tried your regex in my code but it didn't work just like in regexr. There is something wrong about it.

Comment: @TheForgottenWarrior Did you try it like `RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^(?:[a-zA-Z]|\P{L})+$', unicode: true);`? See [Matching Unicode letters with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131876/11329890).

Comment: I didn't add the unicode part but I will try it once I get home.

Comment: It might be a little naïve to treat English as having only ASCII letters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks

Comment: That's nice and working, thank you. Before running a match against this regex, it wouldn't hurt to check the length of the string. Just had to debug a StackOverflow caused by passing an 8K+ character string to Java's `String.matches()` method.